# How can I change the relevant import path from the command line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

everyone.

When I move a typescript file using a shell script, I would like to change the import path of the related file that imports that file.

At work, I was tasked with organizing a project that had a large number of files.
Since multiple people are working on git for the project, the development pipeline cannot be stopped, and it is required to move files in an instant using a script.

The package manager I'm using is npm.

It was difficult to just move it using the mv command.
If there is a better way, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use a shell script, move them with using the file tree in VS Code and tell _it_ to auto-update all the imports? (which it can, since it's basically an IDE with the best support for TS)

Comment: We considered this method within our organization, but there were about 1000 files that needed to be moved, and we wanted to finish the work in an instant to avoid conflicts with other workers during the move, so we decided to create a script in advance. is preferable.

Comment: As an additional note, if we manually move 1000 files, we will make a mistake, so it would like to reproduce it with a script and check in advance whether we can move it accurately.